# example of reduction a polynomial decision to an NP-complete

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, np-hard

I know if I reduce an NP-complete problem to a unknown problem *P* then I'm sure that *P* is itself NP-complete. And I know if I reduce a Problem *P* to an NP-complete problem there is no conclusion. So I want to give an example to show that we can reduce a Polynomial solvable problem *P* to an NP-complete one.

Comment: Maybe this question is better suited for Programmers.SE?

Comment: I raised this question from chapter 34 CLRS about NP-completeness

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I reduce an NP-complete problem to a unknown problem P then I'm
>   sure that P is itself NP-complete

No, this is not well formulated. If an NP-complete problem *A* is reducible to a problem *P* all we can say is that any problem in NP is reducible to *P*. To say that *P* is NP-complete we need to know additionally that *P* is itself in NP.

What you probably intended to say was

> If I reduce an NP-complete problem to **some** <s>a unknown</s>  problem *P* **in NP** then I'm
>   sure that *P* is itself NP-complete

Now to your original question.

> give an example to show that we can reduce a Polynomial solvable
>   problem P to an NP-complete one

Consider the problem known as 2-SAT: *Given a boolean formula in conjunctive normal form such that each disjunction contains at most two variables tell it if is satisfiable*.

Solving this problem following an algorithm by [Aspvall, Plass & Tarjan (1979)](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~sbuss/CourseWeb/Math268_2007WS/2SAT.pdf) involves building an implication graph and finding all its strongly connected components. The paper proves that the formula is satisfiable if and only if the implication graph does not contain a strongly connected component that include some variable together with its negation. It also shows that this algorithm is linear in the size of the formula encoding.

So

1. there exists a linear algorithm for 2-SAT.
2. 2-SAT is reducible to unrestricted boolean satisfiability problem known as SAT.

This gives an example of a polynomially solvable problem (2-SAT) that is reducible to an NP-complete problem (SAT).